# How to use raster extract/clip raster in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, masking

In arcgis, raster like a shp file, could extract another raster.But in Qgis,Raster->Extraction-clip, the mask file must be shp file.
My mask raster are compound of  many adjacent cells. If converted to shp file,
it look like some adjacent cells would combine as polygon. It will reduce extraction accuracy.